# Numerical column in Excel gets converted as logical

Tags: r, excel, numbers, rexcel

When I try to import data into R studio from Excel, the number columns are getting imported as Logical in R.

Is there a way to import these columns as a number into R? The column in Excel has been formatted to number.

I am using `read_excel` to import the file.

The spreadsheet I am trying to import has 80 columns.

Comment: See argument `col_types`. Are those logical values being imported as `NA`?

Comment: They are being imported as true or false, instead of having values.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use `col_types` and explicitly specify the column types.

```
read_excel(path, sheet = 1, col_names = TRUE, col_types = c("text","numeric","date"), na = "", skip = 0)
```

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/readxl/versions/0.1.1/topics/read_excel

Comment: Is there a way to do this without specifying all 80 columns? Can I just specify the column that is getting converted as logical?

Comment: It is better to explicitly specify the column types for all your columns, just in case you input data changes. You could use the function `rep` to make the declaration look concise.

Answer (score 31):

I ran into the exact same problem, and due to confidentiality policies I can not provide the excel file. However, I found the solution in github provided by jennybc in [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/readxl/issues/413), in there she posted:

> "But I'm guessing that you have lots of blank values at the top of this
>   worksheet. Looks like this column is being guessed as logical, and
>   anything that's neither NA nor zero is becoming TRUE. If my diagnosis
>   is correct, you should either specify the column type you want
>   (probably numeric in this case) or increase guess_max to something
>   higher than the default of 1000."

As my files change a bit in format, I went for the `guess_max` suggestion, and this line solves the issue for me:

```
temp.data <- read_xlsx(filepath, sheet = 1, guess_max = 10000)
```

Comment: Thank you, just ran into this problem.

Answer (score 1):

As you did not provide a dataset as an example, I came up with the following dataset:

```
df <- structure(list(`1_a` = c(1212, 1221, 32432), `2_a` = c(121, 123, 3), `3_a` = c(34, 343, 232), 
                 `4_a` = c(65, 23, 123), `5_a` = c(34, 432, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), 
            class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

The dataset are all numeric, with column names starting with a number.

Using the following code, I am able to read the excel file while retaining the column names as they are (test.xlsx being an example of the above dataset):

```
library(readxl)
df <- read_excel("test.xlsx", sheet = 1, col_names = TRUE)
```

Comment: Sorry I am not sure how to add a dataset to this, but I have columns which are text, some have dates. The column in Excel which gets converted as logical in R has blanks and values such as 0.5,1.0,11.4,9.0. These values are getting converted to TRUE/FALSE. Sorry if this does not make sense but I am not sure how to attach a file.

Comment: @Hisho Please update your question. You did not specify the data type that you have obtained and the data type that you require.