# R doesn't show data when reading a data frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame (in excel format) that I'm trying to read into R.

When I use the view function I can see that some columns show only TRUE/FALSE instead of the numeric variable I can see in the excel file I have.

Why does it happen and how can I fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide your example code and/or associated errors/warnings. Initially this sounds like you mismatched the column type when you imported the data. You might need to specify this manually.

Comment: I have a data frame in excel format with number values, but r doesn't seem to read it correctly and just shows TRUE or FALSE. I also tried to change this column with as.numric but it didn't help

Comment: I found my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50947838/numerical-column-in-excel-gets-converted-as-logical